# get type of "Controller" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me that is there any way to get/check the type of controller? In project we are using two different type of controllers. One is API controller and other is MVC controller.
I need to set some session values only for MVC controller(s). For that purpose I need to get the type of controller.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Add some code to see clearer what the problem is.

Comment: You've asked only one question ;).

Comment: @Florian, I do not have any code because I do not know what code to write to get the require infromation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check type of your controller:

```
if (this is Controller)
{
   //Actions when type is controller
}
if (this is ApiController)
{
   //Actions when type is api controller
}
```